# How to disable checkbox if it once checked

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a drop down list having checkbox in it. If I checked some checkbox from the list then those checkbox remains disable but remaining enable for further checking. I am posting a image. Here I am selecting first two checkbox then these checkbox remains disable if I again select same location same type and same block then only remaining checkbox enable in this case last two.

[image]

My JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#loc').on('change',function(){
         $('#type').val('');
     });
    $('#type').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        var locID = $('#loc').val();
        //alert(locID);
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'fetchtype.php',
                data:'country_id='+countryID + '&locID=' + locID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#block').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#block').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        var typeID = $('#type').val();
        //alert(typeID);
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'fetchtype.php',
                data:'state_id='+stateID+ '&typeID=' + typeID,
                success:function(html){
                $('#Flr').html('');
                $('#Flr').multiselect('destroy');
                $('#Flr').html(html);
                $('#Flr').multiselect('refresh');
                $('#Flr').multiselect();
              }
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: As per my understanding if you checked locate1+type1+blocks1 selected and checked quarters(ex:2) and  then selected locate2+type3+blocks3 and checked quarters(ex:3)...if you came back to locate1+type1+blocks1 this checked quarters should be disabled????

Comment: please paste your HTML code here...

Comment: @kranthi yes i think you got it

Comment: can you please update in what all cases your saving quarters information???

Comment: from your question "if i again select same location same type and same block then only remaining checkbox enable in this case last two."  means here checkboxes are in checked state??

Comment: @kranthi sorry i didn't understand

Comment: @kranthi yes brother

Comment: ok....in php you checking checkboxes??

Comment: if yes, add a attribute disable to checkbox.

Comment: @kranthi I used ajax and javascript for checkbox code

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT: i got you...while checking check box only(when your selecting same locate1+type1+blocks1) add disabled attribute to respective checkbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159054/discussion-between-kranthi-and-vaibhav-rawat).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.